# How do I display the output of a support file in main when calling it without syntax errors?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have issues executing a support file (GSUStudent) within the main file (Part2.java).

The support file, GSUStudent (with gradeCalc which is used to determine the grades and how they calculate), is used to scan the first name, last name, and all six grades (2 HW, quizzes, and tests) and then calculate the final grade along with displaying the first name and last name together.

The output should be something such as `Firstname Lastname- Final Average 99.9 and Firstname Lastname- Final Average 72.7`. However, I run into errors whenever I try to call GSUStudent (which includes gradeCalc) to the main Part2.java file.

I attempt to solve this by adding parameters that refer to the two Strings (first/last names; both in quotations) and the 7 doubles (2 quizzes, tests, HW's, and final average), but it prints out those entered values and completely skips over the steps in GSUStudent.java that require the user to input his/her grades. There is no scanning for saving values; it simply skips to the last step and displays the output. Hence, I deleted the Strings/doubles in the parenthesis and am left with an empty parameter for gradeCalc.

Is there a way to call GSUStudent and its gradeCalc to the Part2.java file to execute them?

This is the Part2.java:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Part2
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {


        GSUStudent student1= new GSUStudent(gradeCalc);//I am trying to get the new GSUStudent to call the GSU.java file, and then print out the final results
        GSUStudent student2= new GSUStudent(gradeCalc);

        System.out.println(student1); /*This is supposed to print out something 
 such as (your first name) (your last name)- Final Average (a number)*/
        System.out.println(student2);


      }}
```

This is the GSUStudent.java file:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class GSUStudent //calls GSUStudent
    {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String student_name, student_lastname; //creates string for first and last names
      double studentHomework1, studentHomework2, studentQuiz1, studentQuiz2, studentTest1, studentTest2; //creates 6 doubles
      double finalGrade; //7th double which is calculated from the previous 6 doubles


      String firstName, lastname;
      public GSUStudent (String firstName, String lastName, double homeworkA, double homeworkB, double quizA, double quizB, double testA, double testB, double TheFinalGrade)
      { //assigns the Strings/doubles
       student_name=firstName;
       student_lastname= lastName;
       studentHomework1= homeworkA;
       studentHomework2= homeworkB;
       studentQuiz1= quizA;
       studentQuiz2= quizB;
       studentTest1= testA;
       studentTest2= testB;
       finalGrade= TheFinalGrade;
      }
      //gradeCalc begins here: vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
      public class gradeCalc {
        {




      System.out.println("Student 1 will enter his/her credentials: "); //User enters first name
      System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
      student_name = scan.nextLine();


      System.out.println("Enter your last name: "); //User enters last name; scanning the two Strings
      student_lastname = scan.nextLine();

     //Homework grade section
       System.out.println("\nPlease enter your homework grades."); //User enters grade for both homeworks and those grades are assigned to a value
       System.out.println("\nHomework 1: "); 
        double homeworkA = scan.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Homework 2: ");
        double homeworkB = scan.nextDouble();  
          //Quiz Grade Section

    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your quiz grades"); //User enters quiz grades and those are also stored in values
    System.out.println("\nQuiz 1: ");
     double quizA = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Quiz 2: ");
     double quizB = scan.nextDouble();


     //Test Grade Section

       System.out.println("\nPlease enter your test grades."); //Like before, this scans the user input for test grades and stores them in two separate values
       System.out.println("\nTest 1: ");
        double testA = scan.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Test 2: ");
        double testB = scan.nextDouble();


          double homeworkAverage = ((double)homeworkA + (double)homeworkB)/2; //averages those HW grades
       double quizAverage = ((double)quizA + (double)quizB)/2; //averages quiz grades
       double testAverage = ((double)testA + (double)testB)/2; //averages test grades
       double finalGrade = (testAverage*.40) + (quizAverage*.35) + (homeworkAverage*.25); /*multiplies the grades to their respective weight/value and adds them up
        to calculate the final grade*/
        }
    }
      //gradeCalc ends here: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^




      public void set_all (String firstName, String lastName, double homeworkA, double homeworkB, double quizA, double quizB, double testA, double testB)
      {
       student_name=firstName; //sets the First names and last names
       student_lastname= lastName;
       studentHomework1= homeworkA;
       studentHomework2= homeworkB;
       studentQuiz1= quizA;
       studentQuiz2= quizB;
       studentTest1= testA;
       studentTest2= testB;
      }  

      //all of th following returns the names and grades entered
      public String get_FirstName() {return student_name;}  
      public String get_Lastname() {return student_lastname;}  
      public double get_HomeworkA() {return  studentHomework1;}
      public double get_HomeworkB() {return  studentHomework2;}
      public double get_QuizA() {return  studentQuiz1;}
      public double get_QuizB() {return  studentQuiz2;}
      public double get_TestA() {return  studentTest1;}
      public double get_TestB() {return  studentTest2;}
      public double get_FinalGrade() {return  finalGrade;}

      public String toString() {return student_name+" "+student_lastname+"- Final Average "+finalGrade;} //Firstname Lastname- Final Average #
    }
```

The only problem that I need to understand is how to execute the GSUStudent file within the main Part2 file.

The parameters are empty in the Part2 file for the sake of not initializing anything that is inputted. For example, the program would work well if this is what I inserted: `GSUStudent student1= new GSUStudent("Firstname", "Lastname", 99.9, 99.9, 72.7, 72.7, 88.6, 88.6, 89);`
However, it skips all of the steps in the GSUStudent.java file and simply displays "Firstname Lastname Final Average- (a number)" instead. I want the program to allow the user to type in the names/numbers and then display the user's real first/last names along with the final grade of that user. The program should not skip the steps in GSUStudent, rather, it should call it.

Comment: The line: "This is the GSUStudent.java file:"
is supposed to be a part of the text

Comment: You have an extra bracket ... `class gradeCalc {  {`, and that can't be a class

Comment: Aren't you missing a couple of constructors.. for eg: GSUStudent (gradeCalc  gc){}

Comment: Where would they go if I may ask?